# Building Tkinter GUI that displays , edits, and exports JSON file

Tags: python, json, user-interface, tkinter

I am a beginner with python and am trying to make a GUI with tkinter. The result should be a GUI where you can upload a JSON file and on the left column, all the data in the JSON will be displayed. The next columns are textboxes with options to enter data manually. The Sector box should be a dropdown menu with few options. A JSON file should be exported with the new information added when submitted.

[GUI Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb5Px.jpg)

> Original JSON File Data: {"Test1": "Test1", "Test2": "Test2", "Test 3": "Test 3", "Test 4": "Test 4", "Test 5": "Test 5"}

For example, if I type '$100' in the revenues box and submit, the output JSON file should be:

> {"Test1": "Test1", "Test2": "Test2", "Test 3": "Test 3", "Test 4": "Test 4", "Test 5": "Test 5", "Revenue": "$100"}

With my current code, I am not sure how to get the information from the text boxes, and I do not have the JSON file upload set up yet, just hard-coded.

```
#import necessary modules
import pandas as pd
import json
import tkinter as tk

#read the newline delimited json file into a dataframe, newline delimited jsons require lines=True to succeed
brand = pd.read_json('Testing.json', lines=True)

# Container for info pulled from JSON
data = {}
input_data = dict.fromkeys(['Username', 'Medium', 'Date Posted', 'Country', 'Sector',
                            'Revenue', 'Employees', 'Start', 'Step/War', 'Price/Blitz',
                            'Analysis', 'Additional info', 'Date Sold', 'Buyer'])

# Creating keys and value for data container
for row in brand.itertuples(index=False):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(len(row)):
        data[brand.columns[counter]] = row[counter]
        counter += 1

# TKINTER --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Setting up window
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('1000x1000')
window.title("JSON Sorting")
window.configure(bg='#EEF1DB', padx=250, pady=30)

label = tk.Label(text='Info pulled from JSON')
label.grid(column=2, row=0)

label = tk.Label(text='Manual Filtering/Ordering info')
label.grid(column=4, row=0)

# Displaying JSON info
c = 1
for x in data:

    info = tk.Label(text=x)
    info.grid(column=1, row=c)

    txtbox = tk.Text(window)
    txtbox.configure(height=8, pady=10)
    txtbox.grid(column=2, row=c)
    txtbox.insert(tk.INSERT, data[x])
    c+=1

# Creating Manual Textbox inputs
c = 1
for x in input_data:
    if c <= 8:
        label = tk.Label(text=x)
        label.grid(column=3, row=c)

        txtbox = tk.Text(window)
        txtbox.configure(height=8, pady=10)
        txtbox.grid(column=4, row=c)
    c+=1
    if c >= 8:
        label = tk.Label(text=x)
        label.grid(column=5, row=c-7)

        txtbox = tk.Text(window)
        txtbox.configure(height=8, pady=10)
        txtbox.grid(column=6, row=c-7)

butt = tk.Button(window, text='Submit')
butt.grid(column=2, row=len(data)+1)

window.mainloop()
```

How should I set up the textboxes for the manual input so that it can be submitted with the button, and how to do so while keeping the original JSON information?

Comment: _"I am having trouble getting the information"_ - what does that mean? What sort of trouble are you having? Does the program crash? Does it return the wrong value? Does it not return any value at all? Does it return data in the wrong format or wrong type?

Comment: You have used same variable `txtbox` for all the text boxes, so it only refers to the last one  and you cannot refer to the other ones.  Use a dictionary to store those references instead.